# How to fix Screen Tearing when using Simple Screen Recorder (or any Screen recording apps) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: lts, 22.04

When I try to record my desktop screen using "simple screen recorder" application, the saved/recorded video contains high screen tearing/ glitches(look at the attachment). Please help me to fix this bug.

vedio link: https://youtu.be/D64ikSGpXlY

Comment: It will be difficult for many of us to fix this bug, because few of us actually program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing one of the limitations of Wayland, a relatively young technology that replaces the traditional Xorg display server. One of the issues is that many screen recording tools do not anymore work, or work poorly. How well or poorly a tool works under Wayland may also depend on your graphics card.

You may prefer, at least for a recording session, to work on Xorg. To switch to Xorg, log out, then before entering your password, select "Ubuntu on Xorg" on the cog wheel in the right bottom of the login screen:

[image]